# Cordova Plugin to display audio information and controls on iOS and Android Lockscreen

Tags: android, ios, cordova, audio, cordova-plugins

I am looking for a plugin or plugins that would allow me to show audio metadata (Title, Artwork etc.) on the Lockscreen of both iOS and Android. 
Along with that I would like to control the audio from the lockscreen (Play pause etc, it already happens in iOS I need it happen on Android).
Lastly the plugin should provide audio information within the control center in iOS and the notification area in Android of cause with the ability to Play Pause etc.

If it is easier to do with some native code tweaks then can someone please point that out also to a tutorial as to how it can be done.

Below are some examples of what I am speaking about

[image: Audio information in Control Center iOS]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How did you get along with this in the end? I'm trying to do something similar but having no luck

Comment: @kern do you find any solution for it?

Comment: Nope I didn't end up going native

Answer (score 1):

This plugin does what you're looking for: https://github.com/homerours/cordova-music-controls-plugin

As of writing it has a few issues with iOS html5 audio (see https://github.com/homerours/cordova-music-controls-plugin/issues/97 and https://github.com/homerours/cordova-music-controls-plugin/issues/66) but works across iOS, android and windows phone.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this, however I have never tried it. It uses the native players for iOS and Android, and will not work on chrome or your dev machine.
https://github.com/wnyc/cordova-plugin-playerhater

On my current project I have much the same need as you, (I am using HTML5 audio) and have had to put together a number of different plugins.

iOS Background Audio

https://github.com/AubreyHewes/cordova-background-audio

iOS Meta data:

https://github.com/ChoiZ/NowPlaying
https://github.com/shi11/RemoteControls

I am working on a solution for a modular android audio notification controls using the webintent plugin, but I am far from finishing it. I'll post back here when it's done.

Comment: awesome looking forward to it.

Comment: @tabrindle: do you have anything new since your post?